# Extract certain number patterns from an integer in a vector

Tags: r

For data `Quakes` that looks like:

```
    Date      Latitude   Longitude   M
1 18001011       ...
2 18001122
3 18030000 
4 19001010                        ...
```

`class(Quakes$Date)` gives "integer" and without using regular expressions to grab patterns, how do we extract years, months, and days?

For first row with 18001011, it would be:

```
Year = 1800, Month = 10, Day = 11
```

Comment: use `substr` https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substr.html

Comment: What is the expected day and month for `18030000` ?

Comment: It's kind of random number because I was looking to just take out 4 numbers then 2, 2.

Comment: Well but then the lubridate solution would give you NA for `y <- ymd("18030000"); day(y); month(y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lubridate package can help.

```
library(lubridate)
ymd("18001122")
```

Or:

```
ymd(Quakes$Date)
```

And to extract year and month individually:

```
year(ymd(Quakes$Date))
month(ymd(Quakes$Date))
day(ymd(Quakes$Date))
```

Base-R can also use as.Date() by passing in its format specification such as:

```
as.Date("18001122",format="%Y%m%d")
as.Date(as.character(Quakes$Date),format="%Y%m%d")
```